# How to use class in Groovy for SOAPUI

Tags: java, groovy, soapui, data-driven-tests, test-runner

I would like to use SOAPUI Groovy property for data driven testing. I am able to run the script for Once but while I am trying to use this inside class as OOPS Showing some error. It might be a GroovyUtils scope issue. Please provide solution for the following working code.

The following code replaces xml values and runs the request.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def Req = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("ConversionRate#Request")
def CurrenctFrom = 'USD'
de CurrencyTo = 'INR'
Req["//*:ConversionRate/*:FromCurrency"] = CurrenctFrom
Req.updateProperty()
Req["//*:ConversionRate/*:ToCurrency"] = CurrencyTo
Req.updateProperty()
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['ConversionRate']
testStep.run(testRunner,context)`
```

Same code is not working when executed within a class.

```
test.log = log 
def test1 = new test()
test1.runReq('USD','INR')

class test {
    def static log

    public void runReq(String CurrencyFrom , String CurrencyTo) {
        def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
        def Req = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("ConversionRate#Request")

        Req["//*:ConversionRate/*:FromCurrency"] = CurrenctFrom
        Req.updateProperty()
        Req["//*:ConversionRate/*:ToCurrency"] = CurrencyTo
        Req.updateProperty()
        def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps['ConversionRate']
        testStep.run(testRunner,context)
    }

}
```

WSDL - currency Converter (webservicex)

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: If the script is working fine, then may I request you what is the benefit that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @EistonDsouza post your comment as an answer since it's the solution `:)`

Comment: @albciff He hasn't replied to it yet :D. Still I will :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use it this way, 
`public void runReq(String CurrencyFrom , String CurrencyTo, testRunner, context){....}` and call it as

```
test1.runReq('USD','INR', testRunner, context)
```